# Creating a custom increment in excel

Tags: excel, customization, increment

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a customized increment in excel.

Currently I know we drag an drop columns of values to have increments such as:
10, 11, 12, 13, and etc.

However, can we create one such as this:
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

So when we hit "z" it will start at 0 all over again.

I've been messing around by pasting various values, but so far i can't seem to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a custom list. File > Options > Advanced > Edit Custom Lists

[image]

After that you can start typing anywhere in the sequence and drag the fill handle down.

[image]

Note that custom lists entries are all text, so if you start a sequence with 0, 1, 2 etc, you will have to enter the numbers as text, using a leading single quote like `'0`, `'1`, etc.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.